# RPC error on update EDMX file

Tags: entity-framework-6, edmx

When I want update my entity framework model(.edmx) i have following error

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.Execute(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.FunctionDetailsReader..ctor(EntityCommand command, Version storeSchemaModelVersion)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadFunctionDetails(IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.SchemaDiscovery.EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader.LoadStoreSchemaDetails(IList`1 filters)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GetStoreSchemaDetails(StoreSchemaConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.CreateStoreModel()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String storeModelNamespace, ModelBuilderSettings settings, List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings settings, IVsUtils vsUtils, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext hostContext)'.
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:00.4485064.
Generating the model took 00:00:25.4756427.
```

anyone knows whats this error and how can i fix this error in my application

Comment: Include less tables in your model!

Comment: I can not reduce my tables. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [EF developing team](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/185) if you are using VS2015 or previous version you must install the [EF 6.2 Beta 1 Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55259).

In case of VS2017 you just need to install the latest updates.